# Connecting prometheus with grpc in GoLang

Tags: go, prometheus, grpc

I am not able to see the prometheus metrics on my browser after adding this in my grpc server code:

```
s := grpc.NewServer(
        grpc.StreamInterceptor(grpc_prometheus.StreamServerInterceptor),
        grpc.UnaryInterceptor(grpc_prometheus.UnaryServerInterceptor),
    )
    generatedfiles.RegisterFuncn(s, &RegisterFuncnService{})
    // Register Prometheus metrics handler.
    grpc_prometheus.Register(s)
    http.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
```

Since the above did not work I added :

```
http.ListenAndServe(":8085", nil)
```

Upon adding the above, I am able to see metrics but grpc doesn't work throwing the following error:`could not greet: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded`

Answer (score 0):

Although you're registering the gRPC server, you're missing the step where you start the gRPC server by providing it with a listener.

The code that you copied from [repo](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-prometheus#server-side) is just a snippet showing how you could combine Prometheus with gRPC server code.

See [`server.go`](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-prometheus/blob/master/examples/grpc-server-with-prometheus/server/server.go) for a complete example.

You'll need to add something like the following to the code to start the gRPC server.

```golang
# Listener for gRPC server on :50051
lis, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":50051")
# Start the gRPC server
log.Fatal(s.Server(list))
```

Comment: I have added 
lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":50051")
s.Serve(lis)
however, I am still not able to view the metrics on prometheus

Comment: Your question was that gRPC was not working. The answer explains why it wasn't and what's done to get gRPC working. You said in your question that you are "able to see the metrics". If you have a different issue now, please ask a new question.